# Google Chrome on Mac OS Sierra - Annoying ‘This Website Wants to Open this Application’ warning for Files .mkv .mp4

Tags: mac, macos, google-chrome

**Google Chrome** on **Mac OS** Sierra - Annoying ‘***This Website Wants to Open this Application***’

Sorry have to log this one again as I am newbie and so can’t comment yet.

This box pop up only used to show up for the very first time you downloaded a file from a website program. You then used to click the box ‘remember this’ and that was it. Yes I did the cookie and everything cache refresh on Chrome.

Example of message

*“https://anywebsite.au wants to open this application”*

Someone mentioned ‘Putty’(0.73) and says to download it but this seem like a coding program, so doesn’t help me.

Clicking ”Ask where to save each file before downloading" in preferences - doesn’t work either.

I’m happy to use the option under ~/.config/chromium/Default/Preferences

But Linux is mentioned. Is there an option on MAC OS? Linus is similar I know but….

This is what someone posted.

"download": {
  "directory_upgrade": true,
  "extensions_to_open": "",
  "prompt_for_download": false
},

Any help appreciated but I fear there are lots and lots of people getting bummed off with this issue.

How annoying……its bad enough the browsers security has got so full on, Gmail (for example) has started blocking emails and giving red warnings or just chucking it into spam aaaaaahhhh.

Cheers
Virginia

Comment: The directory `~/.config/chrome` which is used in Linux corresponds to `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` on macOS.

Comment: This post on SuperUser has the answer: https://superuser.com/a/1518982/187103